# Can't find hyper-v virtual machine for HoloLens 2 emulator

Tags: hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

does anybody know why I can't see the HoloLens 2 emulator as a virtual machine in the hyper-v manager? As far as I know, it is hyper-v based. I'm doing this so that I can change the default virtual switch to an external one (virtual as well) so that other client devices can connect to a server on the HoloLens 2 emulator. If I misunderstood something, tell me that as well.

Comment: If anybody else has this problem, the new emulator update (1034) fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The HoloLens 2 Emulator uses the Host Compute Service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20170127-introducing-the-host-compute-service-hcs).  Virtual Machines created in this way are not visible in Hyper-V Manager.  Modifying the virtual machine to use an external network adapter is not supported.  That said, a solution is coming in an emulator update to allow connectivity from other devices.  Please keep an eye on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/hololens-emulator-archive for emulator updates.